# How to select only 1 checkbox from each paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, checkbox

I am working on html survey page and the requirement is to select only 1 checkbox from each row of survey, Survey options might be different, see the screen and html below:
[image]

#### HTML Used

```
 <div class="firstrow"><div class="srno"><p>1.</p></div><div class="survey"><span>I am satisfied with the quality, reliability and speed of the computer I use.</span></div></div>
    <div class="options">
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly agree" value="Strongly agree"><span>Strongly agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Agree" value="Agree"><span>Agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Disagree" value="Disagree"><span>Disagree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly disagree" value="Strongly disagree"><span>Strongly disagree</span></span>
    </div>
<div class="firstrow"><div class="srno"><p>2.</p></div><div class="survey"><span>The Software currently installed on my computer is adequate for my job function.</span></div></div>
   <div class="options">
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly agree" value="Strongly agree"><span>Strongly agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Agree" value="Agree"><span>Agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Disagree" value="Disagree"><span>Disagree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly disagree" value="Strongly disagree"><span>Strongly disagree</span></span>
    </div>
```

How can I achieve this using jquery, I have tried a lot but got success when there is only 1 survey question. when I select another question checkbox this will remove previous  question selected checkbox.

#### Jquery Used

```
$(function () {
   $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
       }
   });
})
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you use radio button instead of checkbox?

Comment: can't you use radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:-*** Actually it's best to use radio button,then no jQuery needed.

***But if you want to go with check-box and jQuery do like below:-***

```js
$(function () {
   $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $(this).parent().siblings().children("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
       }
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstrow"><div class="srno"><p>1.</p></div><div class="survey"><span>I am satisfied with the quality, reliability and speed of the computer I use.</span></div></div>
    <div class="options">
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly agree" value="Strongly agree"><span>Strongly agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Agree" value="Agree"><span>Agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Disagree" value="Disagree"><span>Disagree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly disagree" value="Strongly disagree"><span>Strongly disagree</span></span>
    </div>
<div class="firstrow"><div class="srno"><p>2.</p></div><div class="survey"><span>The Software currently installed on my computer is adequate for my job function.</span></div></div>
   <div class="options">
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly agree" value="Strongly agree"><span>Strongly agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Agree" value="Agree"><span>Agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Disagree" value="Disagree"><span>Disagree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly disagree" value="Strongly disagree"><span>Strongly disagree</span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I have to stick with the design that why I have to work with check-boxes only.though use of ration button is a classical way to do this.

Comment: @RishiJagati  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

To to select only 1 option among the several choices, instead of using `checkbox` use `radio` and give the same name to all radio belongs to a category so that only one radio can be checked at a time.

Ex:

```html
<p>Topic 1
  <input type="radio" name="topic1">One
  <input type="radio" name="topic1">Two
</p>

<p>Topic 2
  <input type="radio" name="topic2">One
  <input type="radio" name="topic2">Two
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="radio" />` instead of `<input type="checkbox" />`

But to fix your jQuery use `.siblings()` instead of `.not(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code **100%** working:

**Demo:** https://output.jsbin.com/ketunanizo

https://jsbin.com/ketunanizo/edit?html,js,output

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="firstrow"><div class="srno"><p>1.</p></div><div class="survey"><span>I am satisfied with the quality, reliability and speed of the computer I use.</span></div></div>
    <div class="options">
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly agree" value="Strongly agree"><span>Strongly agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Agree" value="Agree"><span>Agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Disagree" value="Disagree"><span>Disagree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly disagree" value="Strongly disagree"><span>Strongly disagree</span></span>
    </div>
<div class="firstrow"><div class="srno"><p>2.</p></div><div class="survey"><span>The Software currently installed on my computer is adequate for my job function.</span></div></div>
   <div class="options">
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly agree" value="Strongly agree"><span>Strongly agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Agree" value="Agree"><span>Agree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Disagree" value="Disagree"><span>Disagree</span></span>
        <span class="optpadding"><input type="checkbox" name="Strongly disagree" value="Strongly disagree"><span>Strongly disagree</span></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
   $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $(this).closest('.options').find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
       }
   });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and it will surely work....

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parent().siblings().children().prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```